# Global theme showing update in Discover

Tags: updates, kde, themes

Kubuntu 20.4

I have a theme installed from end of last year that is currently not being used.

Got update notifications this morning when I switched on and that theme is one of the updates.

Besides never recalling seeing a theme updated before this one is **showing 0B** and having looked further into it the **update actually came out in January 2021**.
But is just showing up now.

Am I being a tad paranoid ? Why is is showing the update in August when it was released in January ?

EDIT: Not adding the name of the global theme at the moment, so as not to cause issues for the author if I'm just being overly paranoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you installed your theme, but if it was via package tools (`dpkg`, `apt` etc) and a source is available for it (ie. *you didn't download it using `wget` or equivalent, but added a source such as PPA*) then an update for it would be reasonable.

If you manually installed the package (ie. *did use `wget` or something to download & `dpkg -i` to install the already downloaded package*) an update would be unexpected - EXCEPT if the package exists for your release & that package name was recently upgraded.

I'd likely look at the source of your package using `apt-cache policy <packagename>` to see where it came from, and from what source any updates are available from.

(*As I don't know your package; I opted for `lubuntu-desktop` as a package name; but use the package name in your query; I'd have used a package that has updates available but I have none - I upgrade many times per day*)

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~/uwn/issues/695$   apt-cache policy lubuntu-desktop
lubuntu-desktop:
  Installed: 21.04.1
  Candidate: 21.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 21.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I'd possibly also check they match Ubuntu sources for your release (you can search online using https://packages.ubuntu.com/ but I'd more likely use a CLI tool such as `rmadison` instead of a browser)

ie. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lubuntu-desktop&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all or

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~/uwn/issues/695$  rmadison lubuntu-desktop
 lubuntu-desktop | 0.38    | precise/universe        | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 lubuntu-desktop | 0.55    | trusty/universe         | amd64, armhf, i386, powerpc
 lubuntu-desktop | 0.65    | xenial/universe         | amd64, armhf, i386, powerpc
 lubuntu-desktop | 0.65.3  | xenial-updates/universe | amd64, armhf, i386, powerpc
 lubuntu-desktop | 0.94    | bionic/universe         | amd64, armhf, i386
 lubuntu-desktop | 0.94.1  | bionic-updates/universe | amd64, armhf, i386
 lubuntu-desktop | 20.04.8 | focal/universe          | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 lubuntu-desktop | 21.04.1 | hirsute/universe        | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 lubuntu-desktop | 21.04.1 | impish/universe         | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I used system settings/Global Themes/Get New Global themes to install the theme and just found it strange that the update was available now rather than 6 months ago when the update was released. Especially since I don't have it activated and stayed with the Kubuntu theme anyway.